# ASP.Net application with Cross domain authentication

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication

I have one challenge in my project for cross domain authentication.

Problem: I have ASP.Net MVC app currently authenticated using windows AD authentication (on premise). As Company decided to access this application from outside vendor, we have created B2B connection and then vendor started accessing site but we need to create new users every time in our AD directory. as this is creating more complex as more users started accessing site. user requesting to reuse their own AD account (from their domain) .
How can we setup as if user who from outside trying with his domain account to authenticate system successfully.

Comment: Are these two domains have trust relationship..?

Comment: B2B connection is there but both having different Active directory. Currently we have deployed App in domain X and trying to create all users (AD) in that domains and given details to outside Vendor who going to access application, here problem is users not able to use their own AD account but we are creating users in our AD. I know this is design problem but still we are trying to check if any alternate solution.